# Laravel, how to color a table of navigation if the item name is in the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a table like below: Which does what it should and pull the records for that user from the DB. What I want to do, if a record is in the DB, say 'Bloodborne maws' shows up in the table below, I want to color the td tag in a separate table (navigation table that is static) on the same page with like the color grey.

This table is a set of hyperlinks to different pages, basically if the user visited those pages, they would register at the end and it would record in the DB.
All I want to do is color the td tag if that link has been visited (which means the registered, and an entry is in the DB name 'Bloodborne maws')  for example. Using Laravel blade and can color the table that pulls the records to the blade file, but how to color the td of the table of links to show it has been completed? Kinda stumped here...

```php
@if (count($listings))
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col"><span style="color: gray">Last Name</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span style="color: gray">First Name</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span style="color: gray">Modules</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span style="color: gray">Date / Time (UTC)</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach($listings as $listing)
            <tr>
            <td><span style="color: #007E33">{{$listing->last_name}} </span></td>
            <td><span style="color: #007E33">{{$listing->first_name}} </span></td>
            <td><span style="color: #007E33">{{$listing->module}} </span></td>
            <td><span style="color: gray">{{ $listing->updated_at  }}</span></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
@endif
```

"Other table that I want to turn the TD tag a color if it shows up 1 time for that user in the DB"

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td **"want to turn this green if it is listed in the above table"**>
            <a href="/BP">Bloodborne Maws</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/CSA">Bloodborne hyper</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/CE">Bloodborne status</a></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="/CR">Bloodborne topical</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if i would do this i would put the variables in the array and do the logic from there so that when i populate them in the blade, they will carry the css class they want.

Comment: You can use relationship to accomplish this by defining relationship in models.

Comment: T Shah any example or anything to point me on how to do that?